# Replace new line character with <br> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, newline

I have a string which includes `\n` inside it. I want to display it as new line in a `<div>`.

```
var escapedText = 'Is \n a';
console.log("escapedText: " + escapedText); //it doesn't print \n to console

escapedText.replace(/\\n/g, '<br/>'); 
console.log("escapedText replaced: " + escapedText); //same with above console log

$('#infoText').html(escapedText);
```

It doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You don't do anything with `escapedText.replace(/\\n/g, '<br/>');`. You need to assign it to something.
- You are escaping the backslash for `\n` where you shouldn't be.

```js
var escapedText = 'Is \n a';
console.log("escapedText: " + escapedText); //it doesn't print \n to console

escapedText = escapedText.replace(/\n/g, '<br/>'); 
console.log("escapedText replaced: " + escapedText); //same with above console log

$('#infoText').html(escapedText);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="infoText"></div>
```

Comment: Would this need to be `/\r\n?|\n/` to work cross-platform?

Comment: @thomas Sure. That answers a broader question (: